# Jpeg EXIF metadata date time invalid string

Tags: datetime, coldfusion

Im getting the EXIF metadata from a jpeg in Coldfusion, i need the time from the image, however, when i try and parse the date and time i am getting this error: 
    **2017:06:21 13:39:26 is an invalid time format**

what is the best way to format this date string to be correct using coldfusion?

Comment: Hint: colons in a date are not valid - `2017:06:21`

Comment: @Miguel-F Hi Miguel, yes i know, that is what I'm getting returned from the ImageGetEXIFMetadata function, I was wondering how I can format the sting to be a valid format and then extract the time value

Comment: Change the colons in the date part to dashes. If you have already tried this then shows what you tried by updating your question with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
EXIFdateString = "2017:06:21 13:39:26";
datePartArray = EXIFdateString.split(" ");
newDateValue = parseDateTime(replace(datePartArray[1],":","-","all") & " " & datePartArray[2]);
writeOutput(newDateValue);
```

Outputs:
{ts '2017-06-21 13:39:26'}

At that point, you can format the date part, or the time part, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the date and time as a space delimited list.  This:

```
theTime = "2017:06:21 13:39:26";
writeoutput(listlast(theTime, " "));
```

Returns this:

```
13:39:26
```

And this:

```
theString = "2017:06:21 13:39:26";
theTimeString = listlast(theString, " ");
theTime = createTime(listFirst(theTimeString, ':'), 
    ListGetAt(theTimeString, 2, ':'), 
    ListLast(theTimeString, ':')); 
writeoutput(theTime);
```

Returns this:

```
{ts '1899-12-30 13:39:26'}
```